# Laravel excel export - string formatted column showing as number

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

In localhost i can set the column format as `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING` and its working fine here is the .xls file by using this type

[image]

how ever if i test this in live i get something like
[image]

column values set to `0`.

Why i have tried `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING` format is because the string like `65081035703021` showing as number (base 10) in ms-excel

Whats goes wrong for me?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be 32-bit PHP in live, 64-bit PHP in development

Comment: But displaying a scientific format float isn't related to using STRING rather than NUMERIC datatype for the cell, it's a cell format masking issue; you're using a general format mask by default, and should probably force all the digits to be displayed by using a mask like `00000000000000`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks :), Seems like the first comment is the reason, for the second one i have format the columns as `#0` as you suggest in https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/613, and now its working perfectly, Please share a answer ill accept it, Thanks

Comment: How to make background color in heading?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
namespace App\Exports;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class InvoicesExport implements WithColumnFormatting, WithMapping
{
    public function map($invoice): array
    {
        return [
            $invoice->invoice_number,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($invoice->created_at),
            $invoice->total
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE,
        ];
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html)